# How to use SharePoint user authentication in sharepoint sites

Tags: permissions, site

I have a sharepoint site that inheirts permissions from the main site's portal. These permissions allows anonymous users to view it. For my site I want the user to be asked to provide his username and password first before being able to access the site. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to Stop Inheriting permissions from the parent site, and then you will see Anonymous Access option, click the option and set to None.

[image]

[image]